# In a Spring Web MVC application - how do we break up the architecture into Front-end & Back-end?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, frontend, backend

Looking at the sample Spring Web MVC application PetClinic https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic as an example.

Application typically broken up into 3 different physical tiers and within the server side it is broken into different layers:

Client side: (JavaScript/CSS etc...)

Server side:
- Web
- Service
- Repository

Database:

Using above application as an example what constitutes front-end and back-end?

I always believe everything within the server side (web controllers/service/repositories) + database makes up the backend. But one of my colleague argue that only the database is what 'back-end' is.

Another of my colleague says only the 'Service & Repository' layers constitutes backend and he argue that stuff inside the web layer (consisting of JSP/Thymeleaf templates, form-backing objects, Controllers) is considered 'front-end'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a SpringMVC app the front-end is the **views**. `jsp` files in the **petclinic** app are used to generate `html` files that are served from the server to the client. These files allow the user to **view** the model's data.
- In a web application the backend is certainly not just the database. The controllers are also part of the backend. In a SpringMVC app these are classes annotated with `@Controller`.
- Regarding files the **petclinic** app you may consider everything in `src/main/webapp` as the front-end and everything else the backend. Other people may disagree.
- Mind you that a server app built with SpringMVC may be also used to expose a REST api receiving and transmitting `JSON` documents to a mobile app for instance. This app may implement the MVC pattern itself with its own frontend and backend.

Comment: i think considering everything under webapp folder as front end is definitely a good idea. JSPs are used to generate the views but as the name suggests they are pretty much a backend technology because server side is backend right. Also, JSPs lives under the webapp folder. What's your views on this?

Comment: I tend to consider the V part of any MVC framework as a front-end and in a SpringMVC app that includes html, css, js and jsp. I am entirely aware that this is debatable. Also, I am a backend developer myself and frontend developers may have a different perspective. Mind you an application can have many layers each with its own frontend and backend. One could argue that a mobile app has a front and backend both on the mobile phone and also communicate with a server.

Comment: At [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) in wikipedia : *"The front and back ends may be distributed amongst one or more systems"*

Answer (score 0):

In simple words 
I would say whatever you want display to user irrespective of technology will go in View (Like HTML forms or any informative HTML page).
Regarding backend i would say you want some data to display on Frontend (View in SpringMVC) so you will do any preprocessing which includes getting data from another systems through web services and all , it will go in the backend part.In the same case if you are getting data from DB you can say its backend as well.